# SwiftUI initialising Binding variable without State variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code in SwiftUI:

```
struct VideoList: View {
  @State private var pathList:[String] = []

   var body: some View {
     List($pathList, id: \.self) { path in
         VideoListCell(path: path)
     }
  }
```

And then,

```
   struct VideoListCell: View {
       @Binding var path:String
       private var dateFormatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       ....
   }
```

But I get the error (it builds fine without `dateFormatter`):

```
 'VideoListCell' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
```

And if I declare an initializer like this:

```
    init(path:String) {
       self.path = path
    }
```

I get the following errors:

```
 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

  Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

Comment: You can't initialize a `Binding` with a `String`. You'd need to pass a `Binding` in.

Comment: Huh this is strange, why is the initializer `private`? The default level (when no explicit access modifier is specified) is `internal`. Is there more to this code that we can't see?

Comment: Do you have other `private` properties in `VideoListCell`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: There are other properies in `VideoListCell` but are either optional State vars or initialized private vars.

Comment: @jnpdx How to pass a `Binding`?

Comment: @DeepakSharma `init(path: Binding<String>) { self._path = path }`

Comment: @Sweeper You are absolutely right, a private dateFormatter var is causing issues. I have updated code.

Comment: How about making `dateFormatter` a `let` constant? And if you are going to change it, you should make it a `@State`. Either way will make the initialiser non-private.

Comment: Changing it to `let` solves it. As a side note, should `dateFormatter` be created multiple times in the code? Long back it was recommented to create only one `dateFormatter` in a `UITableView`, not sure if it has changed?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'd recommend storing the format as a `Date.FormatStyle`.

Comment: fyi `id: \.self` will crash, you must use a real `id` when using a state.

Comment: @malhal It doesn't crash. What else can the real `id` be for a `String`?

Comment: `ForEach` works with Identifiable structs for dynamic data in a state, it doesn't work with strings because those don't have an identifier

Comment: You also have a typo, `$pathList` should `pathList`

Comment: It works with `$pathList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dateFormatter` property is a `var`, so it is included in the default memberwise initialiser for structs as an optional argument (because you initialised it). Since it is `private`, the default memberwise initialiser also becomes private.

You should make it a `let` constant. Now it wouldn't be included in the default memberwise initialiser anymore, because it is already initialised and its value cannot change.

You can also make it a `@State var` if you somehow needs to assign another date formatter to it (quite weird). Note that `private var`s don't get included in the memberwise intialiser if they are wrapped with `@State`. This is because `State.wrappedValue` has a non-mutating setter, and so the backing `_dateFormatter` can be a `let`, i.e.

```
private let _dateFormatter = State<DateFormatter>(wrappedValue: DateFormatter())
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    get { _dateFormatter.wrappedValue }
    nonmutating set { _dateFormatter.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

Last but not least, I would suggest changing the type to [`Date.FormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle),

```
private let format: Date.FormatStyle = .dateTime // or some custom format
```

SwiftUI views like `Text` etc can take such a value and format `Date`s automatically.

```
Text(Date(), format: format)
```

Or more generally, a generic type parameter `T: FormatStyle where T.FormatInput == Date, T.FormatOutput == String`. Use `ParseableFormatStyle` instead if you need parsing.